# How to create rss feed in Azure?

Tags: azure, rss

I need to create a RSS feed in Azure. I have an file, i will use the content to create RSS feed.

I didn't get any useful tutorial about it from Azure site and other search engines.

Is there any examples or article about how to create a RSS feed in Azure.

Comment: You can get your RSS feed when its published using Azure Logic but cannot create currently.

Comment: Do you mean i only can use Logic App to read rss feed, but cann't create rss feed to others, right?

Comment: Absolutely it is. Currently you cannot create RSS from azure integrated service like logic apps. If you need how would you read RSS from logic app I can answer for that.